# Bring Stackoverflow Dev Days to Atlanta, GA

Tags: discussion, devdays

Atlanta has a thriving geek community. IgniteATL was recently hosted at the GTRI which is a great venue for Dev Days. Please up vote to bring Dev Days to Atlanta.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1765/devdays-whos-going/1766#1766

Answer (score 3):

Not to mention there are other southern states that don't have a near-by Dev Day. There are a few cities in NC that could work as well.

- Raleigh
- Wilmington
- Fayetteville

all come to mind as they are either great locations or have colleges with quality tech degrees in the area.

Comment: North Carolina isn't that far from Washington, D.C., though.

Comment: True, but its closer to where I live than DC, and helps some others in the Southeastern states. :)

Comment: Wilmington and Fayette 'nam? Ooof. Why not Charlotte. :-)

Comment: Also not to mention the big tech compaines who are here in Raleigh (IBM comes to mind).

Answer (score 1):

Ahem... Nashville'd be great, too.